# Is [the act of something] considered a verb or a noun?

Tags: phrases, verbs, nouns, adverbs

For example, take "Teaching people can be difficult"

Is "teaching people" (the act of teaching people) a noun phrase and "be difficult" the verb phrase, as in being difficult is what the noun phrase does? Or is "teaching people" a verb phrase and "be difficult" an adverb phrase?

Similarly for other sentences such as "Travelling overseas can be eye-opening" and "Jumping rope can be tiring" - I wasn't able to find any like examples elsewhere.

Comment: "Teaching people" is a clause functioning as subject of the sentence. The predicate is the VP "can be difficult". Within that predicate is the subordinate clause "be difficult" which has the adjective "difficult" as predicative complement of the verb "be".

Comment: @BillJ If I were to draw a syntax tree illustrating this, is there a specific way to write "teaching people" to show that it's the subject, or would it just be written as a VP as well? Is having two VP and no subject NP allowed?

Comment: "Teaching people" is a clause consisting of just a VP. Like most non-finite clauses, it has no overt subject. In a tree, it would be labelled 'Subject' (function) / 'clause' (category).

Comment: @BillJ Thank you for your help!

Comment: A classic examples of an ambiguous case is "Flying planes can be dangerous" (for those in planes doing stunts as well as those in the fairgrounds looking up).